# Writing to a new Static html page in php

Tags: php, html, sql, file

I've been asked to create an online sign up sheet. I am almost done but have come to a slight problem. To sign up to an event I  created a new page where they can view the details for the event. However when the text is written to the file about halfway through it starts to write the input as text and not as the html/php code. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

   $sitename = $_POST[eName];
   $title = $_POST[eName];
   $sDate = $_POST[sDate];
   $enDate = $_POST[enDate];
   $exDate = $_POST[exDate];
   $desc = $_POST[desc];
   $pName = $_POST[eName];

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","emuas","flgdls","EMUAS_signUp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO TEST (EventName, StartDate, EndDate, ExpiryDate, PageName, Description)
VALUES
('$_POST[eName]','$_POST[sDate]','$_POST[enDate]','$_POST[exDate]','$_POST[eName]','$_POST[desc]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  $eventID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    $fileStart='<html>
   <head>
   <title>';

   $fileStTable=' </title>
   </head>
   <body>

 <table>
 <tr align="left">
 <th> ';

 $fileSDate=' </th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="left">
 <th> Start Date: </br>';

 $fileEnDate='</th>
 <th> End Date: </br>';

   $fileExDate='</th> 
 <th> Expiry Date: </br>';

 $fileDesc='</th>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <table id =createSheet>
 <tr align="left">
 <th> Description: </br>';

 $fileEnTable='</th>
 </tr>
</table>
';

 $fileStPHP='
 <?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","emuas","flgdls","EMUAS_signUp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sign = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM SIGN_UP_TEST ORDER BY User");

echo "<table> 
<tr> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Status</th> 
<th>Comments</th> 
</tr>"; //Error Starts here. The "; are written as text and so is everything afterwards, until $fileStForm

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sign))
  {
  while($row["EventID"]=';


  $fileEnPHP='echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["User"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["Comments"] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>';

$fileStForm='
<form action="sign_user.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="';

$fileEnForm='" />
<table>
<tr>
<td> Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="user" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Comments: <br /> <input type="text" name="comments" /> <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';

$fileEnd=' </body>
   </html>';


   $fp = fopen("sign_up_sheets/$sitename.html", "w");
   fputs($fp, $fileStart);
   fputs($fp, $title);
   fputs($fp, $fileStTable);
   fputs($fp, $sitename);
   fputs($fp, $fileSDate);
   fputs($fp, $sDate);
   fputs($fp, $fileEnDate);
   fputs($fp, $enDate);
   fputs($fp, $fileExDate);
   fputs($fp, $exDate);
   fputs($fp, $fileDesc);
   fputs($fp, $desc);
   fputs($fp, $fileEnTable);
   fputs($fp, $fileStPHP);
   fputs($fp, $eventID);
   fputs($fp, $fileEnPHP);
   fputs($fp, $fileStForm);
   fputs($fp, $eventID);
   fputs($fp, $fileEnForm);
   fputs($fp, $fileEnd);
   fclose($fp);

mysqli_close($con);

echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Your sheet has been created')
    window.location.href='sign_up.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look at output buffering http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php This should help you with getting your html code

Comment: I had a look, but I'm still very new to php and am a bit out of my depth when I tried to use the ob_start. How would I implemnt it? I mainly got stuck as I have a php tag inside what I need to send to the file

Comment: Your MySQL calls are wide open to SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: The page is password protected by the hosting service. Would that keep it safe or not?

Comment: you need to send the part with html tags to it.Like in the example in that link i sent. so what is your confusion? can you be a little more elaborate? and have your page password protected need not necessarily protect you from sql injections

Answer (score 0):

Of course as wrote Dai your MySQL isn't correct (SQL-injection). I have found some other problems.

1. You are creating php script but saving it as html file `$fp = fopen("sign_up_sheets/$sitename.html", "w");` (Why?) You should use php because your server didn't parse html extension as a php script. This is correct `$fp = fopen("sign_up_sheets/$sitename.php", "w");` (in my opinion)
2. You have some mistake in your while loop. Please look at your `$fileStPHP` variable. 
   You have while in while loop but only outer loop is correct. Maybe you want place there if statement? `while($row["EventID"]='; //inner loop ? But this hasn't got any logical explanation` In my opinion this piece of code should looks similary to this:

:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sign)){
if($row["EventID"]==';
    $fileEnPHP=') {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["User"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["Comments"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```